# Code is not working as i want to fetch data based on filter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

i sent a request to the mongodb to get some data according to email.my client side code is working
properly .
code is here:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    
    const email = user?.email;
    
    // console.log(email)
    
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/services?email=${email}`;
    
    console.log(url)
    
    fetch(url)
    
    .then(res => res.json())
    
    .then(data => setItems(data))
},[user])
```

console.log showing the data as i expected

but the problem start with the backend. i tried console.log to get the email and other thing but the code is not showing nothing even not a single error.
here is the code i wrote for api with express:

```
app.get('/services',async(req,res)=>{
            
            const email = req.query.email;
            
            console.log(email)
            
            const query = {email:email};
            
            const cursor =  serviceCollection.find(query);
            
            const item = await cursor.toArray();
            
            res.send(item);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I didn't see any issue with your code.

Have you tried to call your GET request from the browser directly?

You might check on `req` and `res` to see the incoming data to that endpoint (`/services`)

You also can try to add the request options in your `fetch` method

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

const email = user?.email;
    
const url = `http://localhost:5000/services?email=${email}`;

fetch(url , requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

And I suggest you to using Postman, to call that endpoint. It will easier to debug the API using 3rd party app like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).